# Div expands when the div next to it expands

Tags: c#, html, css, model-view-controller

I have a menu on my layoutpage (MVC) that is on the left side of the page. To the right I have a container that holds the bodypage.

When the sidemenu expands the body expands too. I want the menu to expand but not the body.

How can I rectify this?

```
<div id="divLeftMenu">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="stacked-menu">

<li>
<a class="nav-container" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#stacked-menu" href="#education"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>Utbildning<div class="caret-container"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></div></a>

<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse" id="education">

<li data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#education" href="#education1">

<a class="nav-sub-container">Participants</a>                            

</li>
</ul>

</div>


<div class="container body-content" id=divBodyContent>

</div>
```

I want #divLeftMenu to expand but #divBodyContent should not expand.

Comment: do you even have a container for the whole divs inside this? If not, then you had this problem because of no container. You use bootstrap for this so create a container and a row first.

Comment: Shoudl i have a div with class container and another div with class row around both divs?

Comment: You need to learn 1 fundamental of bootstrap so you can solve and avoid having future problems. You will understand the rest of your problem by giving it at lease 8 mins of your time to understand how the Grid System works. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3j7eRunzv4` don't skip it. This will speed up your understanding on your design. Don't take it for granted.

Comment: Yes bu the problem is that left menu is outside the grid system to the left

Comment: Either one of this will work. 1: Add nav bar Fixed class to your Nav bar. Or add position: fixed to your body content.

Comment: Thanks. Position fixed on #divLeftMenu solved the problem.